# How to detect if the scroll viewer reaches bottom in winrt

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm wondering what's the best approach to detect if a ScrollViewer reaches the bottom, right etc.

I think I can achieve that by using both PointerWheelChanged for mouse and ManipulationDelta for touch. In these event handlers, I can record the HorizontalOffset to find out when will the scroller reach the end. But I think there could be a better way to do it.

I've found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx). But the compression visual states seem not working in winrt. The CurrentStateChanging event method is not getting called.

I also checked another [article](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/winrt-xaml-automatically). But it just works for scroll bar, not a generic approach.

Anyone knows what's the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="sv"
    ViewChanged="OnScrollViewerViewChanged">
    <Rectangle
        x:Name="rect"
        Width="2000"
        Height="2000"
        Fill="Yellow"
        Margin="10" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code behind:

```
private void OnScrollViewerViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var verticalOffset = sv.VerticalOffset;
    var maxVerticalOffset = sv.ScrollableHeight; //sv.ExtentHeight - sv.ViewportHeight;

    if (maxVerticalOffset < 0 ||
        verticalOffset == maxVerticalOffset)
    {
        // Scrolled to bottom
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
    else
    {
        // Not scrolled to bottom
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also checked this method. Though the problem it won't work if the content is not longer than one screen.

Comment: Thank for the update. But I think it actually won't get called in this situation.

Comment: But that's OK, then just start by assuming you are at the end of the list.

Comment: Or wait for the list to first populate before making any checks.

Comment: You are right. Although the idea of my project is changing the UI only after user try to scroll it to the end. I guess I have to user pointer & manipulation methods anyway?

Comment: Getting at the pointer & manipulation events of a ScrollViewer is notoriously elusive and you need to test it with both a mouse and touch input to see the differences. You could modify your content to have MinimumHeight so it always can be scrolled if that helps...

Comment: That's why I'm trying to avoid them :) I'll try your suggestion later. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

For UWP I got it like this

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroll" ViewChanged="scroll_ViewChanged">
    <ListView />
</ScrollViewer>

private void scroll_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
        btnNewUpdates.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void btnNewUpdates_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    itemGridView.ScrollIntoView(itemGridView.Items[0]);
    btnNewUpdates.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: This is great answer. I was searching for this for the last 2 days. It is quite simple. thanks for the help.