# How can I detect if a listbox is completely scrolled?

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I know this question has been asked many many times, but absolutely nothing I found online seems to work.
I have a WinRT/Windows Phone 8.1 listbox, and I simply wish to detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom of it.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12684947/1997232) ?

Comment: You should be able to do this with no code-behind using a converter.  Here is an answer to a different question (having to do with detecting the scroll bar being at the top or bottom) that I posted, which may be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677108/wpf-set-image-visibility-when-scrollviewer-is-scrolled/28679767#28679767